# Can a player play 'Sly Deal' again after 'Just Say No'?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Player A plays a 'Sly Deal' card,
Player B plays 'Just Say No',
Player A plays 'Sly Deal' again.

Is this valid? Will player B able to use the 'Sly Deal' card?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is playing B playing a different Sly Deal card from their hand, or are they trying to play the same card they just played? Checking the rules It seems the first is fine and the second is not.